# Deploy SSRS reports to Sharepoint via ReportService2010 webservice

Tags: asp.net, web-services, sharepoint, reporting-services

Is it possible to deploy reports to SSRS (2008R2/2012) hosted within Sharepoint via the SSRS publish webservice ReportService2010.asmx.  If so, can anyone give any advice on how - specifically, does SSRS (for example) need to be in Sharepoint Integrated mode (and the target Document Library have the registered SSRS Content Types)

We have an SSRS Sharepoint Integrated Instance that we are deploying to, however we are receiving the error message rsItemNotFound - "The item '/' cannot be found" when I make a call to the FindItems web-method within the (ReportService2010.asmx) web service

Notes
- the URL for the webservice we are using is :

```
    http://sharepointUrl/siteCollection/site/_vti_bin/ReportServer/ReportService2010.asmx
```

...which resolves
- we are able to deploy the objects manually (i.e. permissions are OK)
- we can deploy without a problem to a stand-alone SSRS instance via the above process

Answer (score 0):

I've stumbled onto this article a decade late while hunting information on how to migrate SSRS reports. The info below may help someone who is also living in my nightmare.

I am not terribly familiar with legacy SharePoint or SSRS, but I have been a Server Administrator for 10+ years.  I have been tasked with migrating SSRS reports from the On-prem SharePoint 2016 farm to the PowerBI Report server in preparation to decommission the SharePoint server fleet.

Able to VIEW the directory structure and its children using this URL

```
https://SHAREPOINTURL/sites/SITE/SUBSITE/_vti_bin/ReportServer?https%3a%2f%2fSHAREPOINTURL%2fsites%2fSITE%2fSUBSITE&rs:Command=ListChildren
```

Successfully migrated the reports using this command

```
rs.exe -i ssrs_migration.rss -e Mgmt2010 -s "https://SHAREPOINTURL/sites/SITE/SUBSITE/_vti_bin/ReportServer/" -v f="sites/SITE/SUBSITE" -u DOMAIN\USERNAME -p PASSWORD -v ts="https://SSRSserverURL/reportserver16" -v tf="/SSRSFolder" -v tu=DOMAIN\USERNAME -v tp=PASSWORD -v security="True"
```

I worked with a BI team member to craft this command, but sharing because it worked for us.  Hope this helps someone who's banging their head against the wall like I was.